# Textarea com 'disable' não quebra a linha automaticamente

Tags: javascript, summernote

Segue código (com disable):

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: false,
  height: 100,
  callbacks: {
    onInit: function() {
      $('#summernote').summernote('disable');
      $('#summernote').summernote('code', 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
    }
  }
});
```

Segue código (normal) :

```
$('#summernote1').summernote({
  toolbar: false,
  height: 100,
  callbacks: {
    onInit: function() {
      $('#summernote1').summernote('code', 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
    }
  }
});
```

Se preferir JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/204/

Com `disable` o texto fica em horizontal, ela deveria "quebrar a linha", assim como o segundo código.

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se o `Summernote` tem essa opção nativa, mas você pode incluir uma linha para adicionar o estilo `word-wrap` à `div` alterando o estilo e forçando a quebra de linha:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: false,
  height: 100,
  callbacks: {
    onInit: function() {
      $(".note-editable").css('word-wrap','break-word'); // quebra de linha para strings longas
      $('#summernote').summernote('disable');
      $('#summernote').summernote('code', 'kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk');
    }
  }
});
```

Ou então chamar para todos com:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
  $('.note-editable').css("word-wrap","break-word");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/208/)

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Recomendo inserir o código `$(".note-editable").css('word-wrap','break-word');` tanto no `disable` quanto no `normal` (conforme o [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtgr5q29/208/)). No Firefox, sem esse código, mesmo no `normal` não estava quebrando linha.